# Not sure why 'java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect' exception is occuring

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat6

The below thread is in a loop and it just connects to a server, downloads a file, closes the connection and then repeats the process.
The below exception is thrown after approx 500 iterations of the loop -

> java.net.ConnectException: Connection
>   timed out: connect

Why might this be occurring?
Is there a way to kill the thread once the exception is thrown ?

Code -

```
public void run() {

    boolean isExceptionThrown = false;

    try {
    while(true){

        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));

        String inputLine;

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
        {
            //do nothing, just want to read the file
        }

        in.close();

        ++counter;
        System.out.println("Thread id : "+this.threadId+" Connection number : "+counter +" URL : "+urlString);
        }

    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: I see the `tomcat` and `tomcat6` tags how this question is related to tomcat?

Comment: Have you tried the "netstat" command on either the server or the client to check if there are (m)any unclosed connections left by your app?

Comment: I added it to tomcat in case in might be server side issue....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caveat: speculating here. Even though your client code is closing the connection, your server might not be cleaning up quite so quickly, hence your client isn't able to establish a new connection. It certainly sounds like at the ~500 connections mark the server is a bit overwhelmed.

Try putting in something like a sleep for 10s when count == 400 to see if that makes a difference to how many you can process?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you never allow your connections to **fully** close your `Reader` once and letting the thread free resources for the next `while` loop:

There might be too many connection in a thread pool that creating another 1 (while others are trying to close) creates a timeout (that's my guess).

Do this instead (pseudo java code):

```
while (true) {
    BufferedReader in = null;

    try {

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (in != null) {
            try {
                in.close();
            } catch (Exception ignore) {
                ignore.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        in = null;
    }
}
```

Also, give your thread time to "clean" itself before it's completely free from activity. Try to `sleep`/wait for the thread to completely close a connection and free its resources.

Comment: If the timeout happened when opening the connection, the connection isn't established and thus no Reader is created - so you don't have anything to be closed ;)

Comment: @Elite: The code as written will return from `run` once the first exception is thrown. When an exception is *not* thrown `in.close` is called. So failure to call `close` is **not** what is causing the exception. The cleanup time is likely to help.

Comment: Same remark than Cameron, the exception is caught outside of the `while` so there will be at most one unclosed connection. Beside if this was an issue with lingering open connection the error message won't be a time out but something more like *too many open files*

Comment: @tigger, true...in my sampled code, this shouldn't affect the reader as the next loop, the reader (`in`) will still be null.

Answer (score 1):

It could be that the server is getting swamped by too many connections. Even if you close the stream it's possible that the server takes some time to shut down the socket.

The code you have will exit the loop once an exception is thrown because the `catch` block is outside the `while (true)` block. Once `run` returns the thread will die.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I think the thread will exit after printing the stack trace so you should have the kill the thread.

Regarding the reasons, there is not enough information in your question to find out what's the real issue. I think you should also check on the server side to check if downloading forever the same file do not raise an issue on the server side or trigger a protective measure.

It you want to be sure you can use something like [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to check the network activity between the client and the server. You'll probably notice that on the last connection you'll see outbound packets but not inbound ones.